# How to detect the remote app is woring while my app is running

Tags: security, accessibility, detect, remoteapp

i have tried to use Accessibility Service API to detect any kind of remote application's work while my app is running. but once application is shut down, and when i run the app as twice,
it runs properly. here is the problem that i tent to block running if remote application is running when i try to run my app. please comment any sources if there is any component that i can use to detect remote application.

used Accessibility Service API but it worked only once.
other than focused the target application into foreground, Accessibility Service won't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.